# Bad status returned from Mockito test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mockito

I would like to test an example method from the controller

```
@GetMapping("/checkUsernameAtRegistering")
public HttpEntity<Boolean> checkUsernameAtRegistering(@RequestParam String username) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(!userService.existsByUsername(username));
}
```

Which always returns status OK.

I created a test for this in Mockito

```
public class CheckUserDataRestControllerTest {

@Mock
private UserService userService;

@InjectMocks
private CheckUserDataRestController checkUserDataRestController;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(checkUserDataRestController).build();
}

@Test
public void testCheckUsernameAtRegistering() throws Exception {
    mockMvc
            .perform(get("/checkUsernameAtRegistering")
            .param("username", "jonki97"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
}
```

I expect status OK. I know it makes no sense, but I just want the test to be done correctly. However, after successfulfully completed request discarded

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
 <Click to see difference>

    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
        ...
```

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot you should setup your Controller/Mvc test differently for a start.

Firstly, use `@MvcTest`. This loads up a small slice of the context, then `@Autowire` the `MockMvc`. 

What is the rest of your controller? `404` wouldn't be returned unless there is more required for the uri.

Comment: Where is the mock for the `userService`?